# Use Hibernate and Ibatis in the same application

Tags: java, hibernate, ibatis

I need to write a new app but using some data acces logic from other two app. One uses Hibernate and the other uses iBATIS. Can I use in the same app both, Hibernate and iBATIS?. How?.

**Update:** Let me reformule my question. Let's forget I will rehuse some DAOs or domain clases. I need to use in the same app, Hibernate and iBATIS. How can I do that? Thanks for your time...

Comment: What are you going to reuse exactly? Domain classes and DAOs? Are you going to use two datasources? Are you going to merge models into one database? You need to clarify your question a bit.

Answer (score 0):

check appFuse project. it has skeleton implementations for both orms. just combine both of them into the same app. database usually doesn't care what's behind the jdbc driver that accesses it